# How to use AND operator in the same Access query field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to generate a list of clients who have been on 2 specific tours. The query of course works fine when setting the criteria to 1 tour, but when I add the second tour in the same field with AND, no records are returned. The SQL looks like this.

```
SELECT tbl_Customers.LastName, 
       tbl_Customers.FirstName, 
       tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID, 
       tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID
FROM tbl_Customers 
    INNER JOIN tbl_Tour_Bookings 
    ON tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_Tour_Bookings.CustomerID
WHERE (((tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID)="20WJHC") 
AND ((tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID)="24WJHC"));
```

This should be very simple so what am I missing? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: When asking questions on SO .. Please try to make your code readable so that others don't feel like they are struggling to understand what you wrote.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use the `IN` clause to simplify. `WHERE \`tbl_Tour_Bookings\`.\`TourID\` IN ('20WJHC', '24WJHC')`

Comment: This question keeps popping up....  Can someone, who is better at writing English then me , write a GOOD answer ?   Because the use "OR" instead of "AND" is not covering the complete problem......

Comment: May I suggest promoting this question to `sql` only?  The same problem is asked about other DBMSes too.....   

Comment: If OP is wanting to return both tour ID's (which I am assuming is the case since he's calling `tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID` twice -- He will most likely need to use a nested `SELECT`

Comment: Get rid of all those parentheses. They are unbalanced, and NONE of them are needed for this query.

Comment: Access adds the parenthesis when you build a query. Not sure if they are required but this is by design.

Comment: I tried the IN clause but it returns returns records to either tour, similar to what the OR operators does.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to join the two matching conditions on the name which requires subqueries

```
    SELECT 
    t1.last1,
    t1.first1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        tbl_Customers.LastName AS last1,
            tbl_Customers.FirstName AS first1,
            tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID AS id1
    FROM
        tbl_Customers
    INNER JOIN tbl_Tour_Bookings ON tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_Tour_Bookings.CustomerID
    WHERE
        tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID = '20WJHC') AS t1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tbl_Customers.LastName AS last2,
            tbl_Customers.FirstName AS first2,
            tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID AS id2
    FROM
        tbl_Customers
    INNER JOIN tbl_Tour_Bookings ON tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_Tour_Bookings.CustomerID
    WHERE
        tbl_Tour_Bookings.TourID = '24WJHC') AS t2 ON t1.last1 = t2.last2 AND t1.first1 = t2.first2;
```

Comment: The problem is slightly more complicated. With your change you will also see customers who had only 1 of the two tours booked.  From the results of this query only the customers  that had both tours should be in the result (as how I understand the question ...)

Comment: @Luuk yes i see the problem - hopefully the new solution works

Comment: Sounds like we had a similar thought process. As a workaround I created query1 which returns the 2020 trip, query2 returns 2024 trip, then a 3rd query joins the query 1 and 2 via the Customer ID  field. This seems to work but I'm sure there is a more logical way to do this.

Comment: My workaround is not ideal if I wanted to choose multiple trip on the fly but it seems to have solved my immediate issue for these two specific trips for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `WHERE` clause matches to only single/individual records. No single tour has an ID of both `20WJHC` and `24WJHC` at the same time.

The traditional way to solve this issue is to group by the customer, look filter to where the tour IDs are `IN()` the desired set, and then use a `HAVING()` clause to check that the number of rows for that customer matches the number of items you're checking for.